# File upload using HTML and asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, html, json

I want to upload a file, normally excel or word file. the design is like i have an html page having file upload control and this is hosted in server

On uploading the file, the it calls a web service in asp.net to insert data to Database.this is treated as separate application hosted in same server seperatily. 
The data transaction is through JSON.

But i fail to get the file, all other data are clear and it was inserted to DB.

can any one help me to solve this problem..can u please send me a sample to do this...

**sample code**

```
   $(function () {
   //add document button click
       $("#btn_AddDoc").click( function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var InsDocDet = {};
          InsDocDet.docname=$("#ipDocId").val();

          InsDocDet.ownerUser=1;
          InsDocDet.catid=$("#drp_cat").val();
          InsDocDet.createDatetime=new Date();
          InsDocDet.description_d=$("#doc_desc").val();
          InsDocDet.comments_=$("#doc_cmnt").val();
          InsDocDet.deptid_=$("#Drp_dept").val();
          InsDocDet.con_type=1;
          InsDocDet.size_=1;
          InsDocDet.Doc_status="up";
          var fullPath =$("#Upload_doc").val(); //document.getElementById('doc_upload').value;
          if (fullPath) {
              var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
              var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
              if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
              filename = filename.substring(1);
                    InsDocDet.file_name=filename;
                }
          }
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost/Service/Service.asmx/srv_Insert_Document",
              data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(InsDocDet) + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (r) {           
                        console.log("RT");
              }
          });
      });
     //add document--- 

  });
```

Regards,

Sivajith S.

Comment: The are two steps or 'hops' to the approach you describe.  You said 'But i fail to get the file'...Is this true at the first step, i.e. the posting of the HTML page with the FileUpload control?

Comment: i fail to get the file at service,the file properties are saved

Comment: Maybe if you show some code at that point in the execution it would help.  Show us how you process the PostBack and then how you call the WebService from there.

Comment: Can any one tell me how to convert the upload file to base 64 string using script

Answer (score 0):

if this is happening only on server, please do check you have proper read/right permissions of the particular directory in which you are saving the file , also please check that file status is not read-protected(or its resources are free- you get the idea :) ) before trying to access your file #Alok Sharma